# How to use a union type with dynamic a key value in object?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use a union type of two strings passing in one of the strings as an argument then I would like to use this argument as the key for a object property.

```
type TimetabledClass = {
  classCode: string, students: string[]
} | { classCode: string, teachers: string[] }

function getTimetabledClassEnrolments(
  type: 'students' | 'teachers',
  classCode: string
) {
  const timetabledClasses: TimetabledClass[] = [] 

  const enrolments = ['person1', 'person2']

  timetabledClasses.push({
    classCode,
    [type]: enrolments // error!
    // Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string | string[]; classCode: string; }'
    // is not assignable to parameter of type 'TimetabledClass'.
  })

  return timetabledClasses
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that's good to know. I assumed I was doing something wrong. The widening was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by a known issue in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948).  If you have a [computed property name](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) whose type is anything but a single [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), the compiler will widen the type of the key all the way to `string`, resulting in a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), which is often undesirable:

```
function computed<K extends string>(k: K, s: string) {

    const literal = { ["a"]: 123 };
    // const literal: { a: number }

    const union = { [Math.random() < 0.5 ? "x" : "y"]: "abc" };
    // const union: { [x: string]: string } 

    const templateLiteral = { [`a${s}b`]: "abc" };
    // const templateLiteral: { [x: string]: string } 

    const generic = { [k]: 123 };
    // const generic: { [x: string]: number }

}
```

You can see that only `literal` is of a type with a specific key.  The rest, are all widened to a string index signature.

In your code, then, because `type`'s type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string literals, the value `{ classCode,  [type]: enrolments }` is seen as having type `{ [x: string]: string | string[]; classCode: string; }`, which is not assignable to `TimetabledClass`.

---

You could always just [*assert*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that what you're doing is correct:

```
timetabledClasses.push({
    classCode,
    [type]: enrolments
} as TimetabledClass); // okay
```

but it is possible to do a little better via a workaround for microsoft/TypeScript#13948.  I often use a helper function called `kv(k, v)` which produces an object with a property of key `k` and value `v` with a more specific type:

```
function kv<K extends PropertyKey, V>(
    k: K, v: V
): { [P in K]: { [Q in P]: V } }[K] {
    return { [k]: v } as any
}
```

Yes, it uses an assertion, but the point is that this function only has to be written once but can be used in many places, which reduces the overall number of safety holes.

The return type is essentially a *distributive* [`Record<K, V>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) type where a union of key types will become a union of output types. Here's how it works with the examples from `computed()` above:

```
function withKv<K extends string>(k: K, s: string) {

    const literal = kv("a", 123);
    // const literal: { a: number }

    const union = kv(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "x" : "y", "abc");
    // const union: { x: string; } | { y: string; }

    const templateLiteral = kv(`a${s}b`, "abc");
    // const templateLiteral: { [x: `a${string}b`]: string } 

    const generic = kv(k, 123);
    // const generic:  { [P in K]: { [Q in P]: number; }; }[K]

}
```

The type of `literal` is the same literal type as before, but now the other values have stronger types.  The `union` type is itself a union.  The `templateLiteral` type is a [template string pattern index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures), and the `generic` type is still generic.

So we can use the union support in your code to get this:

```
timetabledClasses.push({
    classCode,
    ...kv(type, enrolments)
}); // okay
```

where I'm using [the spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) to convert the output of `kv()` to an inline property.

That compiles without error because the type of the element is seen as

```
const val = { classCode, ...kv(type, enrolments) };
// const val: { students: string[]; classCode: string } | 
//  { teachers: string[]; classCode: string }
```

which is equivalent to `TimetabledClass`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#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-oDgf8wZwedDM4bEUcq2ielKg7lJt4AD49JgRirTh21WMk2hkwhivN05NM1nszl9yEDrPDoUirfx1b0qX7tnyjlcxcKyyEisms272vIdPjQfwtmH5qjk5qIPS6iaBIphuIYUEmBsWwlsuy7WNooQOgIyqEA0NYpgMf5jHIAgCmuOBZHoviIXaVDLqE2HkVAIzfnWVx3A8zaxM8iCvB83x-ACQIgr2-wnr0g6kRWOFMXoE7ysuiBzsoC7SladECMw9CIAAKjAsSOJCjQ4MQADCZKkOQZxKuZpAmXAxA4C+xROA5YBQCUql5Co6GWEp0Q2XZDlOYghA+BA1wMB5k7eWWzqREgqpQLp+lQIZxlmX4pAAKJgDQjT6W5pCCEImmOYgADkWQgK57nlYpFWheFkXlew1mZYFZWTvI1SrlJekGdsRmmTZ5HiMlA1DRlFkxd03nvg0RB5QV7l0io5X0FQpAIEMLUVRtW1gCM5XocIsApWlw2ZeRtwJKQ1x8HYQi1AF9k4K1T0qKVpiLXA+VEO5wjmJmiAIgwNBUAAhEOACCVC5Fs-2IHAwAhUwWnlW4clWnKVr1dF2jThAL1BZ5S4WOVQ4wOQYBwMimUwLkYBpSFcCILQPhtClezI6j6Pjalg3pTZ5W3DUZ0TULV2kDdIB3Q9wjPe1r3vUIn1ozg325b9y2kIDvjkPzF1TaQwMInAyA+EE83IqgtJnP5SsOZwtwu8mpWcD9f2FVUBqAeeiC2-myhVTVUXyt5hPE518qzj0jURZtL4Rw7FkdS+ZYlf1AuTSN0u3fdj2K6nysKy7txu+rHta177nEUIQPTmbFtW0IDhOC4IVZ0bueOgIQA)