# How can one achieve better generic inference

Tags: typescript

Given the example below, are there any ways to achieve DRY code that's similar to `foobarA`?

```js
interface F<T, U extends string> { t: T, f: (u: U) => void }
declare const foo: <T, U extends string>(type: U) => F<T, U>;

// the following correctly types foobar, however 'bar' redundantly repeats.
const foobar = foo<string, 'bar'>('bar')

// ideally one would want the generic inference to be smarter and the
// following to work:
const foobarA = foo<string>('bar')
```

Comment: `foobar` is inferred as `{ [x: string]: (arg: string) => void; }`, is it what you want? https://tsplay.dev/w8Borm

Comment: It is distracting that `T` has no effect on the output type, since you don't seem to be asking about that.   I would suggest that you change your code to something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NV7ZMm) so that `foobar` is known to have a `bar` key.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74636881/2887218) for specifics.

Comment: If you do make such an edit, then the answer is: unfortunately, TypeScript does not support *partial type argument inference* as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242); workarounds include *currying* like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRzRYw)

Comment: @jcalz: that seems to be the best solution available at the moment - thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript does not directly support *partial type argument inference* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  So if you have a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function of the form:

```
declare const foo: <T, U extends string>(u: U) => F<T, U>;
```

there is no way to call it so that you manually specify `T` but let the compiler infer `U`:

```
// const foobarA: F<string, unknown> ☹
const foobar = foo<string, "bar">("bar");
```

Either you have to manually specify both type arguments as in `foo<string, "bar">("bar");` (which is unfortunately redundant) or you let the compiler infer both arguments as in `foo("bar")` (which doesn't infer the right type for `T`).

Until and unless this changes, you will need to work around it.

---

One workaround [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), whereby you split the single generic function call into multiple generic function calls, so that you can manually specify the type argument for the first, and then let the compiler infer the type argument for the second.  That means we'd need to refactor the above `foo()` into

```
declare const foo: <T, >() => <U extends string>(u: U) => F<T, U>;
```

And then we could call the function like this:

```
declare const foo: <T, >() => <U extends string>(u: U) => F<T, U>;
const foobarA = foo<string>()("bar");
// const foobarA: F<string, "bar">
```

It's a bit annoying to have to throw in that extra function call, but syntactically at least it's just another pair of parentheses, and it gives you exactly the behavior you're looking for.

---

Another workaround is to add a *dummy parameter* corresponding to the type argument you'd like to specify manually, and then pass in a value of that type so that the compiler can successfully infer it.  That looks like this:

```
declare const foo: <T, U extends string>(dummyT: T, u: U) => F<T, U>
```

And then we could call the function like this:

```
const foobarA = foo("someString", "bar");
// const foobarA: F<string, "bar">
```

The value `"someString"` passed in for `dummyT` is almost certainly ignored by the function implementation, but it allows the compiler to infer `string` for `T`.  If the caller doesn't have a value of the type handy, they can still use the dummy version by [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that something random is of that type:

```
const foobarB = foo(null! as string, "bar");
// const foobarB: F<string, "bar">
```

Here I've used `null!`, the value is `null` and by [asserting that it is non-`null` via postfix `!`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-), we have an impossible "non-null null" of [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) which can be assigned to any other type. The main benefit of a mind-bending thing like `null!` is that it takes only five keystrokes to produce a value of the impossible `never` type, which can be asserted `as string` without complaint by the compiler.

---

Both versions work; I tend to favor currying unless the use case makes it easy for the caller to find and pass in an appropriate argument for the dummy parameter.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIB4AqAaZBVZCAD0hABMBnZCsKUAcwD5kBvZMALmR2QFcuCAXwCwAKDEg4AWwgUADohQBhOCBAB7MABF1mABbAqLMcmRkICADZwoKBOpA1kMdeq5ZcBYqUrVaDRgAKfnwASmQAXmYMHjxGAG4TZHtHMGdXACMbAEFI9PV0GjoQJkCAIiyoMtD45AB6OsIoKHUoAEIkhuSHJxd1SuyuDCKGXF4QAGsNAHcQZkBOMiSU3sybPL7C-xLcCpsyoN2qmrERUUkZeUVkJV5mgE8GViTzKxs7HrS+9x4g8KjkdBeEgQchUEYlIIhPB-aIefAJJYffIDdauTbFUqhcqVaqJUSmLrLT6rKCDNDo0bIQ77E4SaSyBRIZBaXhSKQPEpPfFmCzWWzdVL5b6eQjA0F+DFBMis9mYLg8KEw8mxRiIwV9FERfLlCjqGQAZS29DKOxxx25hKRGpyQwp2ypONV3KJyJsACFUepAiBeJZLG1kHAwUbTXtzQTGi7rVA3bbwfRQ1UnacgA)

Answer (score 0):

The following will literally “work” — it will compile.  I don’t know if it will actually accomplish what you want.

```
const foo = <S,T extends string = string>(type:T)=>{
  return { 
    [type]: (arg: S)=>console.log(arg)
  }
}
```