# Strongly typing a generic callback parameter based on another parameter's value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a slightly better approach to change validation on angular with some ts generics concepts, and i wrote the code below. It takes in the type of the component so that when I declare the callback, it actually has the correct type. However, as you can see in the function call, I have to write the propertyName it is attached to twice. Is there any way I can turn K into an optional parameter?

```js
export function ifChanged<ComponentType, K extends keyof ComponentType>(
  changes: SimpleChanges,
  prop: K,
  callback: (value: Pick<ComponentType, K>) => void,
): void {
  if (changes[prop as string] !== undefined && changes[prop as string].currentValue !== undefined) {
    callback(changes[prop as string].currentValue);
  }
}

//Function Call
ifChanged<UserFormComponent, 'user'>(changes, 'user', (value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Ideally, I would call this ifChanged function like this:

```js
ifChanged<UserFormComponent>(changes, 'user', (value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

I've also tried swapping the K type declaration with `K extends keyof T = keyof T` but then if I don't add `'user'` to the type generics in the function call, the value inside the callback has the wrong type.

Comment: TS doesn't support *partial type argument inference*; if you manually specify `ComponentType` (ugh long type parameter name) then `K` cannot be inferred.  See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74662987/2887218) for more information.  Does that fully address your question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz geez louise, seems like I found quite a rabbit hole for my afternoon. Thanks a lot. That's precisely it! I'm using T and K in my code, just thought it could help if I changed the names to something more significative haha