# TypeScript doesn't allow assigning a value to a type that uses generic parameters as index types

Tags: typescript

Here's some example code:

```js
function foo<T extends string, T2 extends string>(str1: T, str2: T2) {


   let score: {[K in T | T2] : number}; 
   score = { // Type '{ [x: string]: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ [K in T | T2]: number; }'.(2322)

      [str1] : 1, 
      [str2]: 2
   }
}
```

Something weird is happening here - TypeScript seems to be treating `str1` and `str2` as strings - even though there's no room for those values to change.

Is this a known short coming and does it have a name?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74644134/2887218.  Does that fully address the question or is something missing?